# ServiceBusTrigger batch in Azure WebJob Sdk beta 0.5

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is there a way to retrieve batches of messages from a subscription using the new Azure WebJob Sdk beta 0.5. We're handling quite a few messages per second and would ideally like the following syntax

> public static void ProcessMessages([ServiceBusTrigger("Topic",
>   "Subscription")] IEnumerable brokeredMessages)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible today.

What is the scenario in which you want to use that binding?

Comment: Hi Victor, We're using webjobs to push the data on the servicebus to various databases and would like to batch the writes to improve the throughput. Guess the config.Queues.BatchSize only applies to queue's and not subscriptions?

Comment: For now the BatchSize only applies to Storage queues. Service bus is sequential

Comment: Is this possible today? According to this it's not I suppose? https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1024